# I am trying to identify the brand of this bathtub faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I am wanting to replace this bathtub faucet without changing the plumbing behind the wall. I am assuming by identifying the brand/type of faucet already installed I could have success by getting something similar?

[image: Current faucet]

Comment: Have you attempted to remove the faucet?  Many faucets use similar mounting pipes, so that would actually be a more useful picture.

Comment: I think, unless it's real old, the valves should be a standard size. I think what you need is to verify the sizes by removing the valves and spout. Then you just find one that matches those sizes with separate hot/cold valves. Shouldn't need to re-plumb to change it.

Comment: I will not be physically at the faucet for another week but these comments are providing some hope. If you can be patient with me I will return with a photo of the faucet removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, plumbing fixtures have no constancy. There are many, many different makes, and no company makes the same thing one year to another. They all change their models every year, so finding the same fixture is virtually impossible. That said, the stuff behind the fixture tends to be standardized. The handles are attached to what are called "faucet posts". This is what they look like:

[image: shower faucet posts]

Most ordinary turn handles will work, and if not, hey, just return them for store credit.